# Disable default form input error in angular js

Tags: angularjs

How do I disable the input error message showing by default below the text input  boxes.

Here is my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/Registratonvalidation.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', []).controller("numOnlyRegex", function ($scope)
            {
            $scope.numOnlyRegex = /^\d{1,6}$/;
                    $scope.cityArray = ["hyderabad", "secunderabad", "delhi", "mumbai"];
            }
            .controller('FormSubmitController', function($scope) {
            $scope.submit = function($event)
            {
            if ($scope.myForm.$invalid)
            {
            $scope.myForm.$submitted = true;
                    $event.preventDefault();
            }
            });        </script>
    <!--<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/numOnlyRegex.js"></script>-->
        <title>Registration Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <h2 class="text-muted">Registration form</h2>
                                <!--onSubmit="return validate()"-->
                                <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FormSubmitController" >
                                    <form name="myForm" action="RegistrationServlet.do" method="POST" >
                                        First name:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}/" ng-model="uname" placeholder="First Name" required/>
                                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.pattern">First name cannot be less than 3 letters with no digits</span>
                                        <!--<p ng-show="myForm.uname.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">Your name is required.</p>-->
                                        <br/>                                        
                                        Last name:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="lname" ng-model="lname" name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-]{3,20}/" required placeholder="Last Name"/>
                                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.lname.$error.pattern">First name cannot be less than 3 letters with no digits</span><br/>
                                        <p>Password:
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="pwd" ng-minlength="3" ng-model="pwd" required placeholder="Password"/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pwd.$error.minlength">password cannot be less than 3 letters</span><br/>
                                            Confirm Password:<input type="password" class="form-control input-sm glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="pwd2" ng-minlength="3" ng-model="pwd2" required placeholder="Confirm Password"/><br/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pwd2.$error.minlength">password cannot be less than 3 letters</span><br/>
                                            Gender: <input type="radio" name="female" ng-model="color" value="female" ng-required="!color"/>Female <input type="radio" name="male" ng-model="color" value="male" ng-required="!color"/>Male <br/><br/>
                                            Mobile:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="mobile" ng-pattern="/^[7-9][0-9]{1,9}$/" ng-model="mobile" required placeholder="Mobile"/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.mobile.$error.pattern">Please enter a valid mobile number</span><br/>
                                            Email:<input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" name="email" ng-pattern="/\S+@\S+\.\S+/" ng-model="email" required placeholder="Email"/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$error.pattern">Invalid email address</span><br/>
                                            Address:<textarea class="form-control input-sm" name="address" ng-model="address" required placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.address.$error.require == true">Address cannot be empty</span><br/>
                                            Street:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="street" ng-model="street" required placeholder="Street"/>
                                            Area:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="area" ng-model="area" required placeholder="Area"/><br/>

                                            City: <select name="citySelection" ng-model="city" ng-options="city for city in cityArray" name='city' required>
                                                <option value="">Select city</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <span ng-show="myForm.citySelection.$error.required"></span>
                                            <br/><br/>

                                            State: <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="state" ng-model="state" required placeholder="State"/>
                                            Country: <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="country" ng-model="country" required placeholder="Country"/>
                                            Pin:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-pattern="numOnlyRegex" name="pin" ng-model="pin" required placeholder="Pin"/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pin.$error.pattern">Only six-digit number is allowed</span>
                                            <!--<input type="Submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" ng-submit="submit($event)" value="Submit" />-->
                                            <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" ng-click="submit($event)">Submit</button>
                                            <!--ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"-->
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </body>
</html>
```

Link for the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tHvYYwIHECveA4Salxpy?p=preview)

Comment: Remove 'required' from  the text input boxes.

Comment: If I remove "required" then form will not check for empty/un-filled values

Comment: @kittu   There are lot of errors in your code . That is why it is not working as per your expectation. Please see this updated plunk and I modified the code for the first field alone (uname)  http://plnkr.co/edit/8iSIvw?p=preview. It will validate on tab out.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this method:

```
function validateMethod() {
$scope.isValidated = true;

if($scope.uname == '') {
$scope.isValidated = false ;
}
//other custom validations
return $scope.isValidated;
}
```

MOdify the angular code as:

```
var valid = validateMethod();
if(valid)
{
 $scope.submit = function($event)
            {
            if ($scope.myForm.$invalid)
            {
            $scope.myForm.$submitted = true;
                    $event.preventDefault();
            }
            }); 
}
```

Comment: but I am using regex for first name etc

Comment: yes, that would be taken care of with ng-pattern , you yourself mentioned that form does not check for empty/unfilled values, then this helps.

Comment: I meant all the fields are required and also there are regex patterns for each field. I want to show error message when inputs are incorrect(as the user types in) and form should not be submitted when there are incorrect inputs (Note: I don't want to use ng-disabled)